# Why I get 'not exist type' Vue 3 + Typescript + Vuelidate?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuelidate

Can anybody help with Vue 3 and Vuelidate problem?

I configured the vuelidate for by guide the https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/guide.html.

```
<script lang="ts">
import { required, minLength, maxLength, numeric } from '@vuelidate/validators'
import useVuelidate from '@vuelidate/core'

export default {
   setup () {
     return { v$: useVuelidate() }
},
data () {
return {
  team: { name: '', shortName: '', city: '', stadium: '', founded: 0, conference: '', division: '' },
},
validations () {
return {
  team: {
    name: { required, $autoDirty: true },
    shortName: { required, minLength: minLength(2), maxLengthValue: maxLength(3), $autoDirty: true },
    city: { required, $autoDirty: true },
    stadium: { required, $autoDirty: true },
    founded: { required, numeric, $autoDirty: true },
    conference: { required, $autoDirty: true },
    division: { required, $autoDirty: true }
  }
}
},
methods: {
onSubmit (): void {
  this.v$.$validate()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I try to build the project I always get an exception

```
TS2339: Property 'v$' does not exist on type '{ onSubmit(): void; }'.
127 |   methods: {
128 |     onSubmit (): void {
129 |       this.v$.$validate()
    |            ^^
130 |     }
131 |   }
132 | }
```

Maybe anyone knows why ts don't want to build the code or maybe I do something wrong?

Note:
I tried to install `npm install --save-dev @types/vuelidate` but it didn't help me

Comment: is it not `$v` and not `v$` ?

Comment: I used v$ as it was said in docs: 

Vuelidate builds a validation state, that can be accessed via the exposed Vuelidate property (this is the property name that you return from setup), most commonly called v$ or just v. It is a nested object that follows your validations structure, but with some extra validity related properties.

Comment: You are mixing options and composition API. Stuff you do in setup is not availabel on `this`.

Answer (score -1):

Extending on my comment after checking the guide:
Don't use `methods` in combination with `setup()`, just put the function in setup as well:

```
setup() {
    const v$ = useVuelidate();
    const onSubmit = () => {
        v$.$validate();
    };
    return {
        v$,
        onSubmit,
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Thomas, I think it's strange to not use Setup with Methods, and with your part of code I get an exception 
`runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6800 Uncaught TypeError: v$.$validate is not a function

Comment: @Persei I didn't dig into the documentation I only copied what you were trying to use in your example. So it seems there is no `$validate()` function in this `useVuelidate()`. So check the documentation on how to trigger the validation manually

Comment: `v$` is reactive. So if you want to call any function of `v$` outside of templates, the function must be accessed via the `_value` attribute. 

For example:

```TypeScript
const sendData = async () => {
    const isValid = await v$._value.$validate();
    if(isValid == false) {
        return;
    }
//...
```

Same goes for 

Please note the missing `this` accessor in this example through the usage of the composition API.